# Print Screen страницы

Tags: print, веб-программирование, экран

Существует ли какой нибудь программный способ получить скрин определенной области web-страницы? К примеру мне нужно программным способом обработать img-файл. В него для начала нудно записать нижнюю область открытой страницы. Как это осуществить, сам процесс записи.

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: Извините, а можно узнать что этот код делает?) Так грубо говоря на пальцах объяснить)

Comment: Сначала гляньте комментарии в коде) в хтмл рисуется блок зеленоватый. по кнопке "go" мы копируем див block1 , ставим копию поверх блока и потом ее спускаем вниз, шатаем по синусоиде влево-вправо и убавляем прозрачность, потом удаляем. Собственно, в функции animate может быть что угодно, это уже ваша фантазия. если из animFall убрать последнюю строку, будет просто копирование объекта (block1tmp над block1).

Comment: Ну я глянул, но без общего смысла не разберешься))А можно то что скопировали, сохранить в файл?)Или записать в переменную php?)

Answer (score 1):

Сделать скрин на клиенте и получить его **нельзя**. Это была бы огромная дыра в безопасности, хотя, может, когда-нибудь организуют, но смысла я не вижу. Другой вопрос - уверены ли вы, что вам это именно нужно.

Варианты:

- 1) сервисы типа [webshotspro.com](http://webshotspro.com/), но ждать скрина будете несколько часов
- 2.1) переосмыслить задачу. Мне кажется, есть способ, как передать на сервер html этой части страницы, а дальше долгая порнография с парсингом и рендерингом.
- 2.2) сделать как в демотиваторах - тупо слать несколько полей серверу и далее как в 2.1.

Вообще интересно было бы более подробное описание задачи увидеть, пока непонятки есть.

**UPD** про php - это 2.1. Копирование блока. Прошу прощения за объем)) Вот рабочий код(в FF, у ие прозрачность по-другому ставится). Просто в .html сохраните.

```
<html><head></head><body>
<p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</p>
  <div style="width: 200px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <input type="button" value="go" onclick="animFall('block1')" />
    <div style="width: 200px; text-align: center;border: #0f0 1px dashed; background-color: #efe;" id="block1">ololo</div>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var glNum = 0;
var glID = '';
function animFall(id) {
  glID = id;
  var d = document.getElementById(glID); // нужный блок
  var d2 = d.cloneNode(true); // копируем
  d2.setAttribute('id', glID+'tmp'); // ставим ID
  d2.style.position = 'relative'; //
  d2.style.top = '-'+d.offsetHeight+'px'; // ставим его поверх нашего элемента
  d.parentNode.appendChild(d2); // лепим его к родительскому блоку
  Animate(); // анимируем)
  }
function Animate() {
  var d = document.getElementById(glID+'tmp');
  if (!d) return false;
  glNum+=2;
  with (d.style) {
    marginTop = glNum+'px';
    marginBottom = '-'+glNum+'px';
    marginLeft = (Math.sin(glNum/10)*20)+'px';
    marginRight = (Math.cos(glNum/10)*20)+'px';
    opacity = (100 - glNum)/100;
    }
  if (glNum >= 100) { d.parentNode.removeChild(d); glNum = 0; } // удаление, когда прозрачность < 0
    else setTimeout(Animate, 20);
  }
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Забыл сказать что это не на стороне клиента происходит.
Дело в том что, когда пользователь открывает страницу, сервер генерирует для него свое содержимое. В нижней части страницы, содержимое при открытие каждый раз меняется. Хотелось бы сделать один эффект для страницы, но для этого нужно иметь файл-картинку, как раз с содержимым нижней части страницы.
Не обязательно скринить! Мож есть какие то способы сохранения в файл содержимого frame, div, ячеек таблицы и т.д

Comment: Ну так разбирайте полученный html и сохраняйте, что надо. Тем более, если это картинки, то там будет ссылка img на файл, пусть даже и живущий недолго. Вопрос уточните -- как парсить html?

Comment: Там не картинки, так текст, ссылки и всяко разное, а нужно получить это содержимое в одном файле - рисунке. По типу Print Screen, и у тя картинка с содержимым рабочего стола, так и тут...

Comment: В общем, могу сказать, что html с этим вряд ли справится. Флэш может свой кусок содержимого в BitmapData перевести, а у js средств таких нет. НО: для эффекта вам, может, проще скопировать этот блок? в гугл "javascript cloneNode", а потом можно копии менять прозрачность, положение и пр.

Comment: html конечно же... Мож на php что то есть? А можно немного подробнее про "скопировать блок"?.. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Для клиента, когда-то пробовал баловаться с ActiveX компонентом на Delphi (причем стандартными способами).
Он умеет рендерить всю страничку (вы задаете только Ole контейнер), и получаете свою картинку, чувствую, что если покопаться и вытащить нужную часть странички.
Но в силу обилия коммерческих предложений, не могу найти статью, по которой все делать в гугле, попробуйте поискать по ключевым словам "ActiveX, html to image" и т.п.